# 1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: windows-10, updates, microsoft-access

I have a software application that I wrote which uses Microsoft Jet drivers.

Today I had this error when starting the program:

[image]

I reininstalled my Microsoft Redistributable Engine (2016) and the error went away.

This is not the first time that users have recently had to reinstall the engine after windows has done updates. It seems that windows 10 keeps breaking the system.

The other error that users had been receiving was:

> The operating system is not presently configured to run this application.

Has anyone else been experiencing issues like that after doing updates and are you aware of any way to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A) Microsoft has updated the JET driver likely because of a security or performance issue. They have likely deprecated a function or changed the input parameters.

B) You need to update your code to not use the deprecated function.

Comment: But that is a rather blind statement though. I have 20 years of code. I have no idea what specific item has been affected. For the other users it was *Office 365* that was upgraded by the system that had a side affect of messing up Access Engine Redistributables.

Comment: Welcome to the world of technical debt. You can't expect keywords you used 20 years ago to be used in the same way now. You need to refactor your code to work with the changed functions. You might just find you have a project reference to Jet vX.Y where you need to update the reference.

Comment: My code is core SQL queries. Simple ones to add. update, delete records. There would be some kind of documentation if that was the case. Although I take your point. But I still think this is actually a system breakage caused by Microsoft. Else their would have documentated changed within Visual Studio updated about changes to the API, and they haven't.

Comment: The documentation will be buried deep in the bowels of the KB articles that are bundled with the updates that broke your connection. Needle vs Haystack.

Comment: This has nothing to do with with a missing entry point or ordinal (numeric entry point) in the dll @spikey_richie.  I am assuming that this is what you mean by deprecated function.  It is more likely that Microsoft keeps screwing up the ODBC wiring between the 32 and 64 bit versions.  Point is.. time for Andrew to port code to use another db.  There are many superior free alternatives to Access (SQLite?).  When you port your code, if you isolate it to a data access layer, it will be easy to do next time.